Is it possible to implement the mobile native Map control in MAUI Blazor?
As I understand it, we can't implement native controls within our web view however currently all of my layout including header and bottom navbar are done in Blazor. Preferably I'd like to keep this layout as is and insert a mobile native map in between my layout like the rest of my razor components but I'm not sure if this is possible.
I also don't want to go down the JS map route as this would result in additional costs when integrated with the Google maps SDK.
The only other route I've thought of is maybe splitting my header and navbar into separate web views and including a web view in the middle for most of my razor pages but swapping to a MAUI content page with the map when needed but I'm not sure if you can even use multiple web views at once and if there would be much negative performance impact from this.
Is there any way of being able to implement the native MAUI map control in Blazor Hybrid or will I need to go down an alternative route like the one above?

How do you currently set up your project layout? Can you provide relevant code?

You can display the maui xaml page by adding a popup or bottom sheet to the blazor razorpage, or what you want is to jump from the razorpage to the maui map page?
